# How do I automatically add a character at end of line?

Tags: text-generation

I am very new to vim and would like to know if I could have a script in my `vimrc` file that automatically adds a `;` to the end of every line.

The only exceptions is if the line has the strings `for(`, `while(`, `#include`, `//`, `/*`, `*/` etc.

I would like this to be turned on by default and toggled on and off via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>.

Comment: I would suggest that you learn to program C (or C++, Java, Javascript) better. There are many cases where you do **NOT** want to add a `;`, for example when breaking a function call with many arguments over 2 or more lines... Scripting all of these cases is difficult... You will quickly get used to adding the semicolons, so just hang in there for a little while :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know about that which is why I put `etc.` in my exceptions. This is also why I want to toggle it on and off.

Comment: Expanding on @Carpetsmoker's comment, beware that automatic `;` insertion could even be dangerous if it is not perfect (and no code is perfect).  Imagine the following confusing set of lines: `if (this > is` followed by `&& a + /* check */` followed by `that * is_very(important |` followed by `security | wise))` followed by `do_something();`. If your automatic `;` insertion makes a mistake and puts a `;` at the end of the `if`, then you immediately get a hard-to-detect security bug.

Comment: Furthermore, sometimes this is even impossible to know without actually trying to compile the code. Imagine someone doing this for whatever strange reason: `#define UNTIL(x) while (!(x))`. Then when you write `UNTIL(out_of_bounds)`, it's impossible to know if that's a function call and therefore needs a terminating `;` or a macro that expands to `while` and therefore doesn't need a terminating `;`. If you do insert the `;`, you are in trouble.

Comment: In short, if it were possible to unambiguously understand where there should be a `;`, they wouldn't have added `;` to the language now, would they? ;) Since that's not possible, you can't have a program that correctly inserts it for you either.

Comment: Looks like I wont use this then unless I tell the script to **only** insert at the end of line with the conditions. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I am using visual studio, but I also really like this feature because most of the time I need to add `;` to the end of the line, but I often press the wrong one and then delete and retype it.
I would rather `;` be added automatically every time and then I delete as I need to.

Comment: With so many historical and now no longer needed keys on a computer's keyboard, we can set up new shortcuts to trigger `Jump to end of line, type ;` to perform this action.
Oh, maybe that's not necessary, just `End` + `;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been stated, your list of exceptions is by no means comprehensive and you will probably find that this often creates more problems than it solves.

However, it's still doable and it was kind of fun to write out the code to do so, so here goes:

```
"When hitting Enter, if the line doesn't start with a /*, insert a semicolon
:inoremap <CR> <C-R>=match(getline('.'), '\s*/\*')==-1?';':''<CR><CR>
```

Feel free to expand this regex to capture your conditions above. I didn't want to write all of that out as I feel like it would obfuscate what I was writing and would still not be a complete solution for what your intent is.

You would probably want to only do this for certain filetypes, in which case you'd want to add the `<buffer>` argument to this command and do it inside an `autocmd Filetype` block.

To disable the mapping, you would say `:iunmap <CR>`

Comment: You can't add blank lines now :-) ... There are probably many more situations where this will do unexpected things  !

Comment: Yep, that was the first thing I noticed too. It will also add a semicolon even if the line already has a semicolon at the end of it and fail for many other instances where the end of a line is not the end of a statement. I really hope the code I use above is not used by someone for semicolon insertion, but maybe it will help someone apply these tricks to a different use case. If someone adds enough exceptions that they truly feel that automatic insertion improves their workflow, then good on them.

Comment: On a related note, I sometimes find myself accidentally adding semicolons in python, so I do `inoremap ; _` for those files. Gives me a slightly easier way to type underscores, but when I do type a semicolon at the end of a line, I notice the character change and instantly catch my error.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thank you for pointing this out. Also thank you @_MattBoehm for giving me the starter code. Looks like I will need to add the new line exception too! Looks like a fun challenge! Looks like I will learn vim code and c++ the dame time. Challenge accepted! Will try code tomorrow.

Comment: Could you also show me how to add more then one regex match please?

Comment: You can either try to expand the pattern to match more cases or change `match(...)==-1` to `((match(...)==-1) || (match(...)==-1)). Instead of `||` you may have to escape them as `<BAR><BAR>`.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works however I have tried to edit it and I get a error with this code `inoremap <CR> <C-R>=((match(getline('.'), '\s*/\*')==-1) || (match(getline('.'), '\s*/\int')==-1))?';':''<CR><CR>` The error is `empty buffer`. How would I solve it.

Comment: When I paste that in and replace `|` with `<BAR>` I get no errors. I assume the error is in another part of your vimrc. You can test this by temporarily replacing your vimrc with that one line and seeing if the problem persists. Perhaps you incorrectly tried to use `#` as a comment character?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21644/discussion-between-apydeveloper-and-matt-boehm).

Comment: Here's what finally worked for me: `inoremap <CR> <C-R>=((match(getline('.'), '\s*/\*')==-1) && (match(getline('.'), '\s*/int')==-1))?';':''<CR><CR>`

Comment: First, see [my comment on the question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/how-do-i-automatically-add-a-character-at-end-of-line#comment2198_2347). That said, they very minimum you should do to bypass any trivial bugs is to **try not to parse with regexes**. Regexes are not powerful enough to parse a context-free grammar such as C's. That is assuming no macro wizardry either.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want is an automatic syntax checking. Try [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic). The plugin shows you syntax errors so you don't have to go back and forth to the compiler to catch syntax issues like missing semicolons.

Comment: I have +1ed your comment since it is useful to know however I have not marked this as the answer because it is not automatically adding a semicolon to the end of the line. Thanks for the suggestion though.